# SQL statement with multiple joins and filters returning results back in 1 row

Tags: sql

Can't seem to get my head quite around this problem. I have a data file called Person which houses records for parents (both mother and father). So far with the code below, I can return a row of data which includes pupil and father data. However I also need to include the mother data in the same row, even if the father data is not found and vice versa. I was investigating UNION queries, replicate what I have below for mothers (chenage fatherrelation to motherrelation etc) and try and combine the results together, but I'm wondering if there is a much more simpler and efficient way of doing what I want to to do, which is populate the mother.Title, mother.Forename and mother.surname field.

The following works but only returns the fathers name. I need to get the mothers name as well

```
SELECT DISTINCT(family.pk_FamilyID), family.Salutation, pupil.Title, pupil.Forename, pupil.Surname, father.Title, father.Forename, father.Surname, mother.Title, mother.Forename, mother.Surname
FROM Family
INNER JOIN PersonFamily ON family.pk_FamilyID = personfamily.fk_FamilyID
INNER JOIN Person father ON personfamily.fk_PersonID = father.pk_PersonID
INNER JOIN Relation fatherrelation ON father.pk_PersonID = fatherrelation.fk_RelatedPersonID
INNER JOIN Person pupil ON fatherrelation.fk_PersonID = pupil.pk_PersonID
WHERE fatherrelation.Relationship LIKE '%Father'
AND pupil.pk_PersonID IN('" & Substitute ( ListOfUUID ; ¶ ; "','" ) & "')
ORDER BY pupil.SurnameForename ASC
```

Attempted go without union - I think you can use an OR in an inner join

```
SELECT DISTINCT(family.pk_FamilyID), family.Salutation, pupil.Title, pupil.Forename, pupil.Surname, father.Title, father.Forename, father.Surname, mother.Title, mother.Forename, mother.Surname
FROM Family
INNER JOIN PersonFamily ON family.pk_FamilyID = personfamily.fk_FamilyID
INNER JOIN Person father ON personfamily.fk_PersonID = father.pk_PersonID
INNER JOIN Person mother ON personfamily.fk_PersonID = mother.pk_PersonID
INNER JOIN Relation fatherrelation ON father.pk_PersonID =    fatherrelation.fk_RelatedPersonID
INNER JOIN Relation motherrelation ON mother.pk_PersonID = motherrelation.fk_RelatedPersonID
INNER JOIN Person pupil ON fatherrelation.fk_PersonID = pupil.pk_PersonID
OR motherrelation.fk_PersonID = pupil.pk_PersonID
WHERE fatherrelation.Relationship LIKE '%Father'
OR motherrelation.Relationship LIKE '%Mother'
AND pupil.pk_PersonID IN('" & Substitute ( ListOfUUID ; ¶ ; "','" ) & "')
ORDER BY pupil.SurnameForename ASC
```

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function on a column, it works on the whole selected row! "select distinct(c1), c2" eq. "select distinct c1, c2" eq."select distinct c1, (c2)" etc...

Answer (score 0):

You need to join back to Person again. And I moved your Pupil to be the root of your select since that is what you have PKs for.

```
SELECT family.pk_FamilyID, family.Salutation, pupil.Title, pupil.Forename, pupil.Surname, father.Title, father.Forename, father.Surname, mother.Title, mother.Forename, mother.Surname
FROM Person pupil
INNER JOIN PersonFamily pupilFamily on pupilFamily.fk_person_id = pupil.pk_person_id
INNER JOIN Family on family.pk_family_id = pupilFamily.fk_family_id  
INNER JOIN PersonFamily ON family.pk_FamilyID = personfamily.fk_FamilyID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Person father ON personfamily.fk_PersonID = father.pk_PersonID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Person mother ON personfamily.fk_PersonID = mother.pk_PersonID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Relation fatherrelation ON father.pk_PersonID = fatherrelation.fk_RelatedPersonID
AND fatherrelation.Relationship like '%Father'
LEFT OUTER JOIN Relation motherrelation ON mother.pk_PersonID = motherrelation.fk_RelatedPersonID
AND motherrelation.Relationship like '%Mother'
WHERE pupil.pk_PersonID IN('" & Substitute ( ListOfUUID ; ¶ ; "','" ) & "')
ORDER BY pupil.SurnameForename ASC
```

Comment: Hi Bill,Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it doesn't work because INNER JOIN PersonFamily pupilFamily on pupilFamily.fk_person_id = pupil.pk_person_id will never match. Although the Person table stores all people in my system, The only fk_PersonID's I store in my PersonFamily join table is that of mother and father, and you're trying to link up pupil.personID to that table. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: Ok, but the pattern is established. You join to PersonFamily once for mothers and once for fathers. That should get you to where you need to be.